# Choose template for Angular Directive based on parent controller scope variable

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I define `$items` array in a page controller:

```
$scope.items = [{id:1,type:apple},{id:2,type:banana},{id:3,type:mango}]
```

Then I iterate over this array from a page template:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
    <my-item item-type="{{item.type}}"></my-item>
</div>
```

`myItem` is a directive defined as follows:

```
function () {
    function resolveTemplate(element, attrs) {
        var itemType = '';
        if (itemType === 'apple') {
            return 'apple.html';
        } else {
            return 'default.html';
        }
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: resolveTemplate,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // nothing here
        }
    };
}
```

I've tried to use:

```
scope: {
    'itemType': '@'
}
```

But it appears that I can call `attrs.itemType` only from `link()` and not from `resolveTemplate()` function (where the unprocessed `{{item.type}}` is returned).

So what will be a correct way to dynamically choose a template in this situation?

Comment: you wont be able to do that, during the time of template resolution, variables bound on the same directive would not have been expanded by angular yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From angularjs docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

> Note: You do not currently have the ability to access scope variables
>   from the templateUrl function, since the template is requested before
>   the scope is initialized.

You can however have access to some angularjs service in your resolveTemplate function. So if possible, you can pull in the itemType from the service instead. Your directive would look something like below:

```
app.directive('myDirective', function(templateResolveService){
    function resolveTemplate(element, attrs) {
        var itemType = templateResolveService.getItemType();
        if (itemType === 'apple') {
            return 'apple.html';
        } else {
            return 'default.html';
        }
    }
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: resolveTemplate,
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            // nothing here
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick answer!